# AlertDialog Background is light purple

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using Alert Dialog in my Flutter application it was working fine.
But after upgrading the flutter version to 3.16.0 the backgroundColor property of AlertDialog is not working as expected.

```
void _showDialog() {
    BuildContext? dialogContext;
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
      child: const Text("Cancel"),
      onPressed: () {
        if (dialogContext != null) {
          Navigator.of(dialogContext!).pop();
        }
      },
    );
    Widget emailButton = TextButton(
      child: const Text("Email us"),
      onPressed: () {},
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: const Text("Title"),
      content: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Text('Content'),
      ),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        emailButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        dialogContext = context;
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But after upgrading the flutter version to 3.16.0 the backgroundColor property of AlertDialog is not working as expected.

I assume what you expect is the whole app to look just like before you upgrade to Flutter 3.16, which mean you should opt out of Material 3 (which is enabled by default since Flutter 3.16). You can do this by specifying `useMaterial3: false` in your `ThemeData`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  // ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: false,
    // ...
  ),
);
```

Read more about the changes here:
https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-16-dba6cb1015d1

See also other UI components that are affected by these changes:
[After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293)

Comment: Omg, I spend whole day to edit all the layout until saw this answer, solved !!!!!!

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. Instead of fixing the issue, an entire feature is reverted. The better answer comes from @nateg who tells you how to keep using Material 3 and fix your app to reflect the previous styling.

Comment: @JM_24 Have you read the question body? The asker clearly said _"**was working fine**. But after upgrading the flutter version to 3.16.0 the backgroundColor property of AlertDialog is **not working as expected**"_. The problem is that the asker was not expecting the change that is introduced in Material 3. What asked is the AlertDialog, but most of the case this is just the first difference found, later on people will find out that the other aspects are affected too.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan That is indeed what happens when breaking changes are introduced to tools you are using. Which is why it is important to read changelogs instead of blindly upgrading versions.

The answer you gave serves as a crutch to ignore the fact that Flutter will eventually deprecate the use of Material 2: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/design/material. When the workaround you provided fails, devs will come back with the same problem instead of fixing them now with the properties that already exist to allow them to revert to the previous styling.

Comment: @JM_24 The fact that asker decided to upgrade and not staying on the older version is unrelated to answering the question. You are completely ignoring the fact that Flutter made that `useMaterial3` option to handle this very case. With your thinking, there's only two possible options, which is to stay on the older version or migrate to M3 right after the upgrade, which defeats the purpose of that option. Deprecation and removal of features will happen eventually, and when that happen then it's just another problem to be asked in the future, not related to the current situation.

Comment: OP wants to change the background color in M3--that is the current situation. There IS a way to do that through a single property without using options that will cause issues later. Now OP will continue building their app with M2(!). Your answer doubles down on deprecation. If there is a way to satisfy OP's needs in the current environment, that should be the answer. `useMaterial3` is a great property for apps that were affected by the change and will take time and effort to upgrade. A single dialog box is not time and effort in my book and as such, workarounds should not be given as answers.

Comment: @JM_24 Did you not see that OP said _"it was working fine"_? In OP's mind what's working fine is what he had previously before upgrading to 3.16, which is the M2 style that he might wasn't aware of the difference between M2 and M3. If you're experienced with answering questions, please point out which part of this [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide which my answer violates.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix it by using SurfaceTintColor, which was awesome because I didn't want to disable material3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35542020)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this in Material3. Other answers allude to this answer but don't say where to fix it in your theme for the entire app.

The issue is that Material3 adds a new "surface tint" color to some widgets and not others. Dialogs are one of the widget types that get this tint added to them.

You can fix it by setting this tint color to transparent.

In your theme definition, do this:

```
Color canvasColor = Colors.white;
ThemeData(
  canvasColor: canvasColor,
  dialogBackgroundColor: canvasColor,
  dialogTheme: const DialogTheme(
    backgroundColor: canvasColor,
    surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,  <--- this
  ),
);
```

Comment: Appreciate the global styling answer because this fixes it for the entire app without having to go into each dialog one by one.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it using `surfaceTintColor` property like this:

```dart
 AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                              title: const Text("Title"),
                              content: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: const Text('Content'),
                              ),
                              actions: [],
                            );
```